# 2 images on first line then 3 images on the second line underneath

Tags: css

Using CSS, I want to

- position 2 images next to each other on the first line
- position 3 images on the second line - see attached picture.

[image]

I have tried using the CSS below, but this results in the `3rd` image being on a row of its own.

```
.profile-pic-row:nth-of-type(3){
    display: block;
}

.profile-pic-row {
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

How can I get the `3rd` image to line up with the following `4th` and `5th` images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach with a single `<ul>` and the content always centered

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaPeKZ)

---

**Markup**

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>
   <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
   <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
   <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>  
   <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

ul { 
   list-style: none; 
   font-size: 0; 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   text-align: center; 
}

li { 
   display: inline-block; 
   padding: 10px;
}

/* first and second list-item are 50% wide */
li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2) { width: 50%; }

/* change alignment of inner pictures */
li:nth-child(1) { text-align: right; }
li:nth-child(2) { text-align: left; }

/* just a bit of responsiveness */
li img { max-width: 100%; }
li:nth-child(n+3) { max-width: 30%; }
```

The trick here is to set the width of the first two list-items to `50%` and change their alignment so the first `<li>` has `text-align: right` aligned and the second `text-align: left` (the first two images appear as they were side-by-side)

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you define the third image to be "block" - the block definitions put it in a different line, you need to put "inline-block".

If you want that the 3rd pic will be in a separate line from the previous line from 1st and 2nd pics, you can you `"clear: left":

```
.profile-pic-row{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.profile-pic-row:nth-of-type(3){
    clear: left;
}
```

Or put 2 pictures in one div and 3 pictured in another div and then define the divs to be full row (with "display:block" or "width:100%").

```
<div class="firstRow">
   <img class="profile-pic-row" />
   <img class="profile-pic-row" />
</div>
<div class="secondRow">
   <img class="profile-pic-row" />
   <img class="profile-pic-row" />
   <img class="profile-pic-row" />
</div>
```

Also, you can put every image in a div or a different component, and define width of 50% to the first and second pics, and width of 33% to the pics for the second row.

Comment: thank you, that has fixed my line problem, but they are floated left , how do I get them to be centred like the image I attached above in my question? I'm using Drupal so I can't create the HTML you have above, without creating 2 Views.

Comment: If you can't touch the HTML at all, please post here your current HTML so we can see what we can do